# how to make a border on active menu in the navigation menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

hi i'm attaching part of my css code containing the menu part.

```
#menuwrap {
float:left;
width:861px;
height:50px;
background:#ff284d;
padding:0 0 0 120px;
}
 ul.nav {
list-style:none;
float:left;
font-family: 'Carrois Gothic SC', sans-serif;
margin:21px 0 0 0;
}
 ul.nav li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
font-family: 'Carrois Gothic SC', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:bold;
color:#fff;
padding-right:15px;
}
   ul.nav li a{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;

    }
```

i need to show a different colour box when an item is clicked. where should i change the code?

Edit:: i just need to show the navigation.for that anything just an arrow or a box or border or underline etc.

Comment: You'll need Javascript to do this, CSS wont cut it

Comment: Are you using the wordpress nav menu? If you are, you can use the css class `current-menu-item` #menuwrap .nav .current-menu-item` to get the current page/active page.

Comment: i got the answer with " ul.nav li.current-menu-tem{text-decoration: underline;} "

Comment: Show us your HTML. That's more important in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is WordPress. Your CSS will look something like this (but I need your url to provide you with proper CSS - this is just a rough code):

```
    ul.nav li.current-menu-item a{
    border: 1px solid red; /* this is your border */

}
```

The .current-menu-item class is added to most WordPress temlates navigation menus by default and it is what we use to target active / selected menus.